# Executing multiple methods same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, task

I have a couple of methods that are independent of one another and I was curious which is the best way to execute them at the same time.  I tried these ways below and timed each one and the timing seems to be the same across the board, so I am not sure if I am doing something wrong...?

Also, this is a web application and the methods are called after the user clicks on a button.  C#, aspx

```
method1(var1, var2, var3);  // takes 5 seconds to run
method2(var1, var2, var3);  // takes about 1-2 seconds to run
```

First trial:

```
//Entered my methods one right after another
method1(var1, var2, var3);
method2(var1, var2, var3);
//timed the execution and overall took ~5-6 seconds to run and display results
```

Second trial:

```
//used Google and found something called Parallel
Parallel.Invoke(() =>
{
   method1(var1, var2, var3);
},
() =>
{
   method2(var1, var2, var3);
});
//~5-6 seconds to run and display results
```

Third trial:

```
//used Google and found something called Tasks
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method1(var1, var2, var3));
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method2(var1, var2, var3));
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
//~5-6 seconds to run and display results
```

Fourth trial (similar to Third):

```
//used Google and found something called Tasks
Task[] tasks = new Task[2]
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method1(var1, var2, var3)),
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method2(var1, var2, var3))
};
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
//~5-6 seconds to run and display results
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 3rd and 4th tests do the exact same thing. Your 2nd test is functionally equivalent to the other two.

Your methods should be running in parallel (even though there's [no guarantees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx)).

You don't seem to be timing these tests with any kind of meaningful precision though. Try printing messages from within those methods, at the beginning and at the end, and I'm sure you'll see `method2` start before `method1` finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I think what I was also expecting to see was for "method2" to be displayed on the screen before "method1" because of the shorter time it takes to execute.  But what ends up happening is both results are displayed on the screen at the same time after the 5-6 second of my manually counting.

Comment: @Jayarikahs Are you printing those results from within each method individually? Or from the calling code, after `Task.WaitAll`?

Comment: Within each method, I am binding the data to their own gridview and so the results would be from within each individual method.

Comment: Also, MS generally recommends `Task.Run()` over `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, unless you need the extra complexity (which you probably don't). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx.

Comment: @Jayarikahs Is there a chance that the binding involves any kind of synchronization, such as locking? That could be the problem. If you want to get more help, you'll have to post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jayarikahs - If your methods are directly posting data to a UI element, you'll almost certainly end up with some sort of a thread synchronization problem, since any UI interaction takes place on the main UI thread. A better way to handle that is to do the heavy calculations on a separate thread, but don't update the UI element within that method. What that method should do is to post the results back manually to the UI thread, which can then update the UI elements.

Comment: @KenSmith, thanks for the article.  For what I am doing, there's nothing too complex with it.

Comment: @dcastro, I am not sure to be honest, but I do not think so?  Basically, method1 and method2 are executing 2 separate and independent SQL statements against Oracle.  And both statements are querying different tables, but I am using the same schema to perform both statements.

Comment: @KenSmith, thanks for the tip about threading.  I am not too familiar with using those yet, so I will need to do more research before I test out your suggestion.